# adding Glabel to form a triangle java program

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class test extends GraphicsProgram {
private static final int LABELGAP = 30;
private static final int LINEGAP = 20;
int numLabel = 1;
double y = 75;
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        GLabel label = new GLabel("Hello World");
        label.setFont("London-12");
        double x = (getWidth() - label.getWidth() * numLabel - LABELGAP * (numLabel -1)) / 2;
        double step = label.getWidth() + LABELGAP;
        for (int j = 0; j < numLabel; j++) {                    
            add(label, x, y);
            x += step;                  
        }           
        numLabel++; 
        y += LINEGAP;
    }
}
```

}

But there is only one label per line. What's wrong?
I want to have one more label than previous line.
Also, if I put

```
GLabel label = new GLabel("Hello World");
label.setFont("London-12");
double x = (getWidth() - label.getWidth() * numLabel - LABELGAP * (numLabel -1)) / 2;
double step = label.getWidth() + LABELGAP;
```

This part of the code outside of 2nd for loop, the result is different from when I put them inside(neither is the desired result). Why?

Comment: 1) What is the point of `x += step; `, since you always recalculate the "x" value inside the loop. 2) Do some basic debugging by displaying the x/y values that you calculate to make sure they make sense. That is maybe you add multiple labels but you can't see them because they are off the screen?

Comment: I previously put label constructor statements outside of the second for loop, thats why I need to keep track of x inside of it. I edit the question.

Comment: Don't think they are off screen, the pixel values are small

Comment: I don't know why you are using such a complicated formula to calculate the "x" value.  Start with simple logic. That is, set x to 0, for each row. Get the simple logic working. Then you have proven that the correct number of labels have been added and displayed.